# Which namespace is correct, "com.typesafe.sbt" or "com.github.sbt"?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

[www.scala-sbt.org](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/gettingstarted.html) uses the "com.typesafe.sbt" namespace for sbt-native-packager, [sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io](https://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gettingstarted.html) uses the "com.github.sbt" namespace. Both sites appear to be official, but which one should I follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `com.github.sbt` is the repository of the new releases: https://github.com/scala-steward-org/scala-steward/pull/2263

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand very well.